# Spawning keys and specific doors in endless runner game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am currently developing an endless runner game where you have to dodge the obstacles and once in a while, a key will spawn and you have to pick which door belong to the key you just obtained.

My problem is, I have no idea how to spawn the key and also make sure that at least 1 door that can be opened using the key is spawned couple distance after the key spawn point.

[This is the key and door system that I made. You can only open the door based on the key (capsule) you collect. For example, red capsule to open red door](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PI74.png).

[This is my current game, simple straight line while avoiding obstacles. But once in a while, I would like to spawn keys and doors instead of obstacles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI22S.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you spawn a door (which the player will encounter in the future) you also spawn a key between the player and that door. Make sure to create your maze well in advance of player reaching the "edge" and do not spawn the key next to the door or next to the player.

In Unity you usually want to spawn all tiles next to tiles that the player can see. If your player can see the distance equal to one side of a tile, you need to make sure that all tiles next to the tile the player walks into have been spawned. In this case, I would suggest you also spawn squares beyond those squares, placing a door on a "far away" square and a key on the recently spawned square (that the player just can start seeing).

This has a downside if the game is of the open world type - the player will be able to predict in what direction the door will be (approximately) when the player finds the key. In your specific case where the player has to run in only one direction, it should be easy to use this algorithm.

The system you have created seems just fine.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I'm looking for, but have no clue how do I implement it in C#. Currently I have a "ground tile" prefabs where there's a plane contains 3 spawnpoints for obstacles and 1 nextSpawnPoint for the next tile to spawn. This is the only prefab that I use to spawn "maps" on real time following the camera of the player.  Can you elaborate how should I do to spawn key and door?

Comment: I've added another picture for better understanding of the game. It's a kids learning game so it's okay for the player to predict the direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

if you make the keys into prefabs, you can have a script attach to it that has a ID

```
public class Key: MonoBehaviour
{
public int _ID = 0;
}
```

and you can change the id for each prefabs before you create them, when you check if the keys match the door you check the ID

you can instantiate the prefabs to spawn them

```
instantiate(prefab,position,Quaternion.identity)
```

and depending on how you do the logic for spawning the doors and keys, you keep track of what id is already spawned and go from there

Comment: This will help me creating the door and keys thank you! But I don't know how to spawn the door and keys randomly.  I manage to spawn obstacles randomly and 3 different spawnpoints but how do I spawn key and door (at least 1 door that matched) instead of obstacles once in a while?

Comment: Sounds like you have a mix of questions here.. Focus on what at a time.. Is your question how to pick a random item from a list? Or how to make sure there is a matching door? or how to spawn objects in general?

Comment: @derHugo I believe the third one was my initial question. But it's alright tho as I've figured it out.

Comment: make a list of prefab and instantiate from the list, shouldnt be too different from how u spawn the obstacles